# RewriteRule and seo friendly address

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo, http-status-code-301

So far, my website has been working on the following addresses:
domain.com/item.php?id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

I wanted to change to seo friendly addresses and added to htaccess

```
RewriteCond% {REQUEST_FILENAME}! -F
RewriteCond% {REQUEST_FILENAME}! -D
RewriteRule ^item/([^/]{14}) /item.php?id=$1 [L]
```

And it works great after entering the address:

```
domain.com/item/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

the content of the relevant page is displayed.

So that there would be no problem with duplicate content in the page code, I added:

```
<link rel = "canonical" href = "https://www.domena.com/item/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
```

I am only wondering that google has both url addresses indexed now. Shouldn't it be done on 301 redirects and if so, how, because in rewrite rules I'm not too strong? Thank you in advance for the hint.

I tried also writing [R=301,L] instead of [L] but then if I click address:

```
domain.com/item/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

in address field of the browser I can see:

```
domain.com/item.php?id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Greetings,

Mark

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because SEO questions are off-topic. Only programming-related SEO questions are acceptable on Stack Overflow. Non-programming SEO questions should be asked on Webmasters.SE at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Why are there so many spaces in your rewrite rule (`^ item / ([^ /] {14})`)?   Are those supposed to be there?  Usually using spaces would mean you'd have to use quotes around that part of the rule.  But it doesn't look to me like having those spaces there makes sense.

Comment: @rob Rewrites and regular expressions are considered "programming" here, so I wouldn't close this particular question for that reason. [Are questions about webserver config files and rewrite rules on-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261726/are-questions-about-webserver-config-files-and-rewrite-rules-on-topic)

Comment: @StephenOstermiller it was a mistake of copy/paste. There are no spaces there. I revised a question.

Comment: @Rob It is not SEO related topic as I don't ask about seo strategy but about a code of htaccess for RewriteRules.